# How to disable Prevent Cross-Site Tracking in SafariViewController

Tags: ios

I need to disable Prevent Cross-Site in my app which using SafariViewController.
I already disable the prevent Cross-site in the Safari setting in my iphone. but this setting not work for SafariViewController.
Is it need to add some configuration when init SFSafariViewController?

SFSafariViewControllerConfiguration* config = [[SFSafariViewControllerConfiguration alloc] init];

Comment: I am looking for same type of solution. did you get a solution for this?